# Does the DOS plotted by p4vasp already have Fermi energy subtracted?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, density-of-states

I have used both `SUMO` and `P4VASP` to generate a DOS plot. I have found that there's a shift (displacement) between the two DOS generated by the two computer programs. I am wondering which software has already subtracted the Fermi energy, or did both do that?

Comment: +1 but since we have a policy on asking only 1 question per post I've removed the second question, which you can ask separately. Also please take a look at the changes I made to the tags!

Comment: You should show your plot. If you use VASP and the valence band maximum is set to zero, then the corresponding plot is shifted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the SUMO [DOS documentation page](https://smtg-ucl.github.io/sumo/sumo-dosplot.html) we have that the option `--no-shift` controls when to shift the Fermi energy or not:

```
--no-shift

    don’t shift the VBM/Fermi level to 0 eV

    Default: True
```

In the case of P4VASP, from its page related to [plotting DOS](http://www.p4vasp.at/#/doc/dosbands):

> In all DOS/bandstructure graphs is the energy relative to the Fermi energy - i.e. the Fermi energy on the graph is zero.